# How to open the list of apps from the same publisher on the marketplace?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Opening the url "http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/store/publishers?publisherId=" opens in the browser, doesn't go the built-in store app. Is there any custom url for this?

Using a `MarketplaceSearchTask` with my publisher name as the search term also doesn't work, other apps from other publishers also appear

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is little old, but I'm facing this issue as many do.

Microsoft doesn't offer an option to open market place with only publisher apps.

Search is not bad idea but it will show your apps and possibly other apps.

maybe the best solution is to do the following

```html
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();

webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/store/publishers?publisherId=Phonemenon", UriKind.Absolute);

webBrowserTask.Show();
```

but again this way it will open the browser not the market place

Answer (score 0):

Because the store doesn't have a specific way of just showing the apps by a specific publisher, the option available is to search. As you've discovered there's no way to hint to the search that the term provided is a publisher name it may pick up other things too.
One hack I have seen used is to add custom keyword on all the apps by a publisher that is far more likely to be unique and searching for that. Something like "apps-by-code-beside". The search currently picks up keywords and a value like this is unlikely to show up other apps.

As an alternative, you may be able to provide a better experience by directing people to apps listed on your own website. This could contain appropriate links to the specific apps in the store. As a publisher has more and more apps it becomes less likely that all will be relevant to the person using one of them. It may be more appropriate to show only the relevant apps(relative to the obe being used) linked directly to the store. Yes, this can be more work but it provides you, the publisher, with greater control and, hopefully, the people using the apps with a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code work

```
       var search = new MarketplaceSearchTask { SearchTerms = "your subscription name" };
       search.Show();
```

so you can find all the applications that match your name on the store.

Comment: As I stated in the question, that returns more than just the applications from that publisher

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `MarketPlaceSearchTask` to open the marketplace.

```
//Search for an application, which is the default content type.
MarketplaceSearchTask marketplaceSearchTask = new MarketplaceSearchTask();

marketplaceSearchTask.SearchTerms = "\"RT Apps\"";

marketplaceSearchTask.Show();
```

If you open up the market place on your phone and search for my publisher name with quotations around it, it shows just the apps I wrote. So, my hypothesis is that if you do something like "\"RT Apps\"" as your Search Term it will open the market with just my apps.

## EDIT

Using your publisher name this is the results. You will note that only your content show up.

[image]

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394001%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: If I do that some other completely unrelated apps also show up

Comment: Putting the publisher id in the search term doesn't work, putting the publisher name makes 5 other apps appear in the results, and one of them even appears before one of mine

Comment: For my publisher name, "Code Beside", it doesn't work, even with quotes

Comment: @GustavoGuerra you need to add quotations in

Comment: Those last two apps aren't mine, only the first three

Comment: I'm setting the content type

Comment: Hmmm well this is the recommended method and how you do it so it must be broke for you. Try reporting it to Microsoft.